# Is there a diary function in bash (to start and stop logging)?

Tags: bash

So I was playing around with the language Octave, and they had this useful command called `diary` that would log stdout into a file for anything in between the `diary on` and `diary off`

```
diary on
a = [4 5, 2 6, 2 1]
a + 1
diary off
```

The above would save a file called diary in the working directory with the output of a, then a+1. It was super helpful for debugging, especially when looking at large datasets.

I was looking at other scripting languages and wondered if they have equivalents. The best I could come up with was `echo hello.dat >> diary.txt` for every single line. Does a tool exist that could achieve this functionality for bash? If not, how about python? It seems like a basic thing, but idk how to do it.

Comment: Do you want to log only stdout? Stdout and stderr both? Should content still be mirrored to the TTY as well?

Comment: Take a look at this post: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25639/how-to-automatically-record-all-your-terminal-sessions-with-script-utility

Comment: @codeforester, not quite equivalent insofar as `script` creates a new shell, so one can't stop the log but keep new shell-local variables.

Comment: BTW, the "octave" tag should only be used if someone who knows octave can reasonably be expected to be able to answer the question.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, I'm not so sure about that. Your answer appears to demonstrate a slight misunderstanding of what the question is asking for, and I'd expect someone familiar with *both* octave and bash to be able to answer more accurately.

Comment: @ghoti, I'm inclined to call it reasonable to put the onus on the OP to make the question clear about exactly what constitutes a complete and useful answer, w/o needing knowledge of an almost-unrelated problem domain.

Comment: Yeah to be fair, bash treats the stdout of just the variable name differently since it just substitutes in variables into the command rather than printing it's contents. The use case I had in mind was when I was SSHing into a ubuntu instance with `screen -r` and wanted to selectively save just some of the stdout output of .bash_history.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, no question the onus is on the OP, but I'd posit that "I'd like X to behave like Y" could be considered to be in both domains. (But never mind, I have no skin in this game. :) )

Comment: If I figure out how to do it, I think I will write a command that does this.

Comment: @ghoti, to an extent, I hear you -- but what does "behaves like Y" mean when "Y" is a language with incompatibly-different constructs? For example, if you run the assignment `(( a=5 ))` in bash, the return value of that command is 0. Even if you know Octave, you don't definitively know if the OP wants to print the value *of the assignment* or the value *that was assigned* -- assuming that in Octave those two are the same thing, deciding how they translate to bash is a judgment call, and thus a question of intent w/ its answer unstated here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need contents to keep going to the TTY, and want to redirect both stdout and stderr:

```
exec 3>&1 4>&2 >>diary.txt 2>&1
echo "Everything here goes to diary.txt"
echo "...without having to redirect each line separately"
exec >&3 2>&4
```

If you *do* need contents to keep going to the TTY:

```
exec 3>&1 4>&2 > >(tee -a diary.txt) 2>&1
echo "Everything here goes to diary.txt"
echo "...without having to redirect each line separately"
exec >&3 2>&4
```

Note that you can't redirect both stdout and stderr to the file without either losing their ordering (ie. having two separate copies of `tee` and having to *hope* that they finish flushing in the same order in which you started writing to them) or lose information on which piece of output went to which descriptor.

The above can also be done with a multi-line block with a single redirection, which will do both the setup and the cleanup automatically:

```
{
  echo "Everything here goes to diary.txt"
  echo "...without having to redirect each line separately"
} >>diary.txt 2>&1
```

Comment: Nice! Sorry I'm still a bash noob can you explain what 2>&1 operation means?

Comment: Redirects FD 2 (stderr) to point to the same place as FD 1 (stdout). See [BashFAQ #55](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/055) and its links.

Comment: So .. as fun as this is, I think it's not really what `diary` does in octave. Consider Python's interactive mode. If you just type a variable name, it shows you the content of the variable. Octave's `diary` will implicitly do this after each assignment. If functionality like this exists, I'd expect it to be a `set` or `shopt` thing.

Comment: @ghoti, ...gotcha. I'd argue that the OP needs to extend the question to be more clear about what they want. Could probably do something sorta' like this in bash with a custom `PS4` combined with `set -x`.